# select common rows and non-common rows between 2 tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have 2 tables with names `kcc_201` and `Kcc_300`.

**table kcc_201 looks like this**

```
ClientMarketCode | WorkDate   | OverDraft
123              | 2012-12-12 | 34.5
456              | 2012-12-12 | 60
98               | 2012-12-12 | 80
```

**table kcc_300 looks like this**

```
ClientMarketCode | WorkDate   | DebitAmount
123              | 2012-12-12 | 80
456              | 2012-12-12 | 90
966              | 2012-12-12 | 100
100              | 2012-12-12 | 787
```

My question is what is the query that gets me all clients rows having the same `ClientMarketCode` and `workdate` matches between 2 tables and retrive also non matched rows from 2 tables without using `union`

What query get me result like this:

```
clientMarketcode | WorkDate   | OverDraft | DebitAmount
123              | 2012-12-12 | 34.5      | 80
456              | 2012-12-12 | 60        | 90
98               | 2012-12-12 | 80        | null
966              | 2012-12-12 | null      | 100
100              | 2012-12-12 | null      | 787
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a `FULL OUTER JOIN` similar to this:

```
select 
    coalesce(k2.ClientMarketCode, k3.ClientMarketCode) ClientMarketCode,
    coalesce(k2.WorkDate, k3.WorkDate) WorkDate,
    k2.OverDraft,
    k3.DebitAmount
from kcc_201 k2
full outer join kcc_300 k3
  on k2.ClientMarketCode = k3.ClientMarketCode
  and k2.WorkDate = k3.WorkDate;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6a914/10)

The result is:

```
| CLIENTMARKETCODE |   WORKDATE | OVERDRAFT | DEBITAMOUNT |
------------------------------------------------------------
|              123 | 2012-12-12 |        34 |          80 |
|              456 | 2012-12-12 |        60 |          90 |
|               98 | 2012-12-12 |        80 |      (null) |
|              966 | 2012-12-12 |    (null) |         100 |
|              100 | 2012-12-12 |    (null) |         787 |
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select 

isnull(kcc_201.clientMarketcode,kcc_300.clientMarketcode),
isnull(kcc_201.WorkDate,kcc_300.WorkDate),
kcc_201.OverDraft,
kcc_300.DebitAmount


from  kcc_201
FULL JOIN kcc_300 on kcc_201.clientMarketcode=kcc_300.clientMarketcode
                     and kcc_201.WorkDate=kcc_300.WorkDate
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple, Use FULL OUTER JOIN,

```
select nullif(k1.ClientMarketCode, k2.ClientMarketCode) as ClientMarketCode,
       nullif(k1.WorkDate, k2.WorkDate) as WorkDate,
       k1.OverDraft,
       k2.DebitAmount
from kcc_201 k1 full outer join kcc_300 k2 
on k1.ClientMarketCode = k2.ClientMarketCode
and k1.WorkDate = k2.WorkDate;
```